# Plotting a 2D histogram in matplotlib with different sized arrays

Tags: arrays, matplotlib, histogram

I am trying to make a 2D histogram using data from an h5 file. This file contains calculations of the Chi1 angle of an amino acid for 100 iterations and the values for each Chi angle are stored as a list of arrays within the file. I want to make a histogram of the values of the Chi1 angle for each iteration. In short, I want the x-axis to be the Chi1 angles and the y-axis to be iteration number. Here is the code that I have tried:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

auxdata = [] #An empty list
iteration = [] #An empty list
for i in range(1,100): #100 iterations of calculations
  string = "iterations/iter_" + str(i).zfill(8) + "/auxdata" + "/Trp43_Chi1" #Going to the right place in the h5 file to find the data I want
  f = h5py.File("west.h5") #Loading in the h5 file
  Chi1 = f[string] #Defining x-axis variable
  iter_variable = i #Defining y-axis variable
  auxdata_iter = auxdata + list(Chi1[:]) #X-axis variable becomes a list of arrays of varied sizes
  iter_data = iteration + list([iter_variable]) # Y-axis variable becomes an array of a single value, which is the iteration number


###Plotting###
plt.hist2d(auxdata_iter, iter_data, bins=(100)); #2D histogram divided into 100 bins
plt.xlabel("Trp43 Chi1");
plt.ylabel("Frequency");
plt.title("GB1 Trp43 Chi1 Angle Distribution");
plt.savefig("Trp43_Chi1.png")
```

The problem is that I get the error "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()". 
What I need to learn how to do is to map every Chi1 angle value (x-axis) from a given iteration to the iteration number (y-axis). 
Do you have any ideas? Thanks!